# destroying buttons from a vcontainer

Tags: c, linux, gtk

I have a vcontainer which is populated with a gtk_combo_box and several buttons
i would like to clear the buttons only from within the vcontainer, I tried the following code:

```
GList *vcontainer_children, *iter;
  vcontainer_children = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(container));
  for(iter = vcontainer_children; iter != NULL; iter = g_list_next(iter))
  {
    if (gtk_button_get_label(iter));
      gtk_widget_destroy(GTK_WIDGET(iter->data));
  }
```

the code clears all widgets in the vcontainer, one possibility would be to replace the if with a function that checks whether iter is a button or not, but I do not know how that is done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if (gtk_button_get_label(iter));
```

The semicolon at the end is wrong; this is the same as saying

```
    if (gtk_button_get_label(iter))
        /* do nothing */;
```

and as such the `gtk_widget_destroy()` always runs.

Simply remove the semicolon or switch to using braces for everything (or some other option I didn't think of).

Your condition is also wrong for two reasons. First, it uses `iter` instead of `iter->data`. Second, it will crash and burn spectacularly if the widget isn't a button. Fortunately there's a macro `GTK_IS_BUTTON()` you can use instead:

```
    if (GTK_IS_BUTTON(iter->data))
        gtk_widget_destroy(GTK_WIDGET(iter->data));
```